# Failed to register service worker - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, service-worker-events

Service worker failed to register with the following exception.

`Failed to register ServiceWorker. The origin of the provider scriptURL('https://dev.xyz.cdn.com') does not match the current origin ('https://dev.xyz.com').`

Currently all the assets are deployed in CDN. So domain is not matching with script source url.  How to resolve this issue?

Comment: main service worker resource must be same-origin

Answer (score 2):

You can't host service workers on a CDN. From [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#origin-restriction):

> A service worker executes in the registering service worker client's origin. One of the advanced concerns that major applications would encounter is whether they can be hosted from a CDN. By definition, these are servers in other places, often on other origins. Therefore, service workers cannot be hosted on CDNs.